# accessing two mysql databases from one php file

Tags: php, mysql

this is what i currently do:
i create 2 connections:

```
$con_1 = mysql_connect('xxxxxxxx', 'db1', 'xxxxx') or die(mysql_error());
$con_2 = mysql_connect('xxxxxxxx', 'db2', 'xxxxx') or die(mysql_error());
```

the before each query, i do

```
mysql_select_db('db1', $con_1);
... query
```

but apparently that doesn't work. mysql_query requires me to pass in the $con_1 as well. so If I have to pass in the connection, may i skip the step of calling mysql_select_db all together?

OR, can I just call each mysql_select_db in the beginning and later when I call the query functions, just pass in the $con_x, and not have to worry about selecting the db?

Comment: Why are you still using `mysql_*` functions? [They're deprecated.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database selection is associated with the connection resource. So you can select it once for each connection.

If you don't call `mysql_select_db` at all, all your queries will need to specify explicit database prefixes before all the tables, e.g. `select * from db1.table ...`.

Answer (score 1):

> so If I have to pass in the connection, may i skip the step of calling mysql_select_db all together?

You'll have to call it *once* after establishing the connection

---

But, like @Barmar mentioned in his answer, you wont even need to call `mysql_select_db()` and and you don't need to have two seperate connections for that. You'll just have to use fully qualified table names in your queries, like `dbname`.`tablename`. Check this example:

```
$con = mysql_connect(...);

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `db1`.`foo`');
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `db2`.`bar`');
```